# Accessing an AWS Lambda function from a java web application application is done over Https or Http

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am accessing a lambda function from my java code and I would like to know if I am using Https or Https for that request. How can I do that.

This is how my method looks like.

```
public interface FileScanService {

   @LambdaFunction( functionName = "s3-antivirus-api-scan" )
   public FileScanOutput scanFile( FileScanInput fileScanInput );
}
```

PS: this method is fully functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: See the comment by Michael below. It turns out there is a way how to do it directly via HTTPS.

A Lambda function is not invoked directly via HTTP, so the answer to your question is neither. Instead, it is invoked by one or more of the [event sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html).

It can however sit behind an API Gateway which would enable it being (indirectly) invoked by an HTTP request. In that case, the request is [transformed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-api-gateway-request) into an invocation event and that is what your Lambda function operates with.

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: This is not the complete answer, because Lambda functions can also be directly invoked using the SDKs which call the Service [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Reference.html) and this *does* use HTTPS.  The [Lambda regional endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) used in both that case, as well as on the back-side of API Gateway, do not support HTTP -- only HTTPS.