# Is there a way to find out every resource that calls a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that gets called from several place through out an large app. Is there a way to discover every resource that is calling/using/attached to that lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [Cloudtrail to track function invocations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html#tracking-function-invocations).

If it's an option, when you log in to the Lambda web console, you should see all the triggers enabled for that particular function in the UI.

Comment: [Remembering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223658/1695906), of course, that Lambda functions are not always invoked by triggers.